# How to group the following strings by regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the string I want to process.(At least one of the underlined parts. The last part is never underlined
)

```
'_A._B._C._D._F.f'`
```

I expected

```
["A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "f"]
```

How to achieve the same effect by regularity, I tried, but can't loop the same format part.

```
new RegExp('^[(_(.+)\\.)]+(.+)$')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could exclude dot and underscore from matching.

```js
var string = '_A._B._C._D._F.f',
    result = string.match(/[^._]+/g);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

How about that without using regex?

```js
str = '_A._B._C._D._F.f'.split('.')
var alphabets = str.map(c => c.replace('_', ''));
console.log(alphabets);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Scheinin Your welcome sir, glad it helps you somehow :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` that removes `[._]+` (any substring containing dots or floors) and the `filter` (to remove the initial empty string):

```
'_A._B._C._D._F.f'.split(/[._]+/).filter(function(s){ return s.length > 0})
# => [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "f" ]
```

EDIT:
Simplification suggested in comments:

```
'_A._B._C._D._F.f'.split(/[._]+/).filter(Boolean)
# =>  [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "f" ]
```

Comment: What do you mean? JS is not my native lang :)

Comment: .filter(Boolean)

Comment: thanks, guys, nicer version indeed (updated my answer)!

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In your regex you try to match the whole pattern using an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string followed by a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which will match  only one out of several characters (and might for example also be written as `[_(+\\.)]+`) and then you capture the rest of the string in a capturing group and assert the end of the line `$`.

If you want to check the format of the string first, you might use a more exact pattern. When that pattern matches, you could do a case insensitive match for a single character as the pattern is already validated:

```js
const regex = /^_[A-Z](?:\._[A-Z])+\.[a-z]$/;
const str = `_A._B._C._D._F.f`;

if (regex.test(str)) {
  console.log(str.match(/[a-z]/ig));
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HnBzEw/1)

That will match:

- `^` Assert the start of the strin
- `_[A-Z]` Match an underscore and an uppercase character
- `(?:\._[A-Z])+` 1+ times repeated grouping structure to match `._` followed by an uppercase character
- `\.[a-z]` Match a dot and a lowercase character
- `$` Assert the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

string method .match with global flag, can help you:

```js
console.log('_A._B._C._D._F.f'.match(/[a-z]+/gi))
```

Comment: Thank you very much